# Flash Builder trying to use wrong player

Tags: google-chrome, flash-builder

When trying to run or debug in Flash Builder, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\plugins\NPSWF32.dll

Flash Builder cannot locate the required version of Adobe Flash Player. You might need to install the Flash Player or reinstall Flash Builder.

Do you want to try to run your application with the current version?
```

I've checked the setting in preferences > flash builder > debug and it is pointing to

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\player\win\11.4\FlashPlayerDebugger.exe
```

Yet as you can see from the previous message Flash Builder is still trying to use the chrome version of flash player. How do I actually change this setting to use the right version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by installing the plugin version of the debugger (for netscape compatible browsers) found [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). I then had to go to chrome://plugins/ and disable the pepflashplayer.dll version of the player. Apparently chrome comes with the standard version of flash player preinstalled, and I guess flash builder was trying to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Open the property of current project(e.g. HelloWorld), and go to Run/Debug Settings, double click the project, uncheck the "Use default" and choose "HelloWorld.swf", not "HelloWorld.html".

Answer (score 0):

Updated fix:

1. Download and install the `Active-X` flash player debugger.
2. Test in `Flashbuilder` by setting your default browser to `IE`.
3. Download the `Opera` and `Chromium` debugger and install.

Now the `Flashbuilder` debugger should work with `Chrome`, also.

I discovered this by accident but I have tried it on two separate installs of `FlashBuilder 4.6` and the debugger works in `Chrome` and `IE`.